# Running a regular expression on a String using Linq

Tags: c#, regex, string, linq

I have a String, I wish to use Linq to run a regular expression to cut down my string to a smaller sub-string which matches my reg ex.

My code at the moment gives the error

> 'char' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension
>   method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be
>   found

My code :

```
string variable = result.Name.Select(r => regEx.Match(r.Name).Groups[2].ToString());
```

`Result.Name` is a string contained in a custom class.

What have I done incorrectly? What is wrong with my syntax/understanding ?

Comment: Why can't you just use the Regex?

Comment: Select() will transform each character of your string to something else. You have to apply a regex to your string so why you're using Select?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `Select` on a single string. `Select` is treating your string as a series of characters, and so the `r` in your lambda expression is a `char`.

If you only have a single string you want to pass into your regular expression, and you only want a single match out, then you don't need LINQ at all. Just call

```
string variable = regEx.Match(result.Name).Groups[2].ToString();
```

(I'm assuming `result.Name` is your single string, based on your example code.)

Answer (score 20):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
string[] result = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
                       .Cast<Match>()
                       .Select(match => match.Groups[2].Value)
                       .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
string variable = result.Select(r => regEx.Match(r.Name).Groups[2].ToString());
```

if you run Select on the Name field, you are running it on a string which is an array of char

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
string result = result.Name.Select(@regEx => Regex.Match(match.Groups[2].ToString(), @regEx));
```